# Laravel Mail::fake() working on local but not on Github actions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I have a small PHPUnit test in my Laravel 10 application which tests to see if a verification email is sent after user registration ... It works fine on my local machine, but once I push to GitHub actions it fails;

In my `phpunit.xml` I have the following;

```
<env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
```

My test looks like so;

```php
public function it_sends_email_verification_when_user_registers(): void
{
    Mail::fake();

    $this->postJson('/register', [
        'first_name' => 'Testing',
        'last_name' => 'User',
        'email' => 'testuser@example.com',
    ])
        ->assertCreated();

    Mail::assertSent(VerifyEmailMail::class, function ($mail) {
        return $mail->hasTo('testuser@example.com');
    });
}
```

Always works locally with no issues. But on actions i see;

> The expected [App\Mail\VerifyEmailMail] mailable was not sent. Failed
> asserting that false is true.

Comment: There must be some exception somewhere, check the logs. Set you environment to exact same as you're doing on github actions and then re-run the pipelines locally

Comment: as @UnderDog said, what you can do if you are not able to see the logs is adding `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` before the `postJson`, and you will see the literal exception

Comment: @matiaslauriti ... That just gave me the same error message as above

Comment: @CodeSauce that is good, then it means you do not have an exception, it is not reaching the line that should trigger the mail. You will now have to debug each line until you find the culprit. If you have the same stuff as in your local, then you are missing an environment variable that you do have in your local `.env` but not on your `phpunit.xml`, do this, rename your `.env` to something else, and run it again, and slowly start adding environment variables like `APP_KEY`, until you have no more config errors and you have the same error as you are describing. You can also share you code...